# Does Nektar Impact LX49+ MIDI keyboard work with LMMS?

Tags: midi, daw, keyboard

I am considering purchasing a Nektar Impact LX49+ MIDI keyboard, but before I do I want to make sure it will work with the Linux DAW called LMMS. Have any of you used this keyboard with lmms? Did you run into any problems that you couldn't fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Impact outputs MIDI. LMMS uses MIDI.

MIDI is a pretty good standard, and any controller presented to the interface can be assigned in LMMS.

The [Using MIDI](https://docs.lmms.io/user-manual/4-production/4.5-using-midi) part of the LMMS documentation is very useful and explanatory.